# How to pass values from the Terraform output without putting it in the tfvars file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

everything good?

I am studying how to make an eks deployment using terraform , as a good practice I separated it into modules to make it reusable , but when I run the plan in `testcluster-vpc` , the generated outputs are the public and private subnets and vpc_id , how do I use these parameters without needing to put these values in `terraform.tfvars` inside the `testcluster` folder ?

I thought about using Data Sources , but it didn't work it still asks to pass the values during the plan

I put the structure to get a sense

```
├── testclusters
│   ├── config.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
├── testclusters-vpc
│   ├── config.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
├── modules
│   ├── cluster
│   │   ├── eks_control_plane.tf
│   │   ├── eks_workers.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── eks-control-plane
│   │   ├── iam.tf
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   ├── security-groups.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── eks-vpc
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── eks-workers
│       ├── authconfig.tf
│       ├── iam.tf
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       ├── security-groups.tf
│       ├── user-data.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└── terraform-state
    ├── config.tf
    ├── terraform-state-dynamodb.tf
    ├── terraform-state-s3.tf
    ├── terraform.tfstate
    ├── terraform.tfstate.backup
    ├── terraform.tfvars
    └── variables.tf
```

```
module "testcluster" {
  source                = "../modules/cluster"
  vpc_id                = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id # var.vpc_id
  public_subnets        = data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids # var.public_subnet_ids
  private_subnets       = data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids # var.private_subnet_ids
  cluster_full_name     = "${var.clusters_name_prefix}-${terraform.workspace}"
  cluster_version       = var.cluster_version
  workers_instance_type = var.workers_instance_type
  workers_ami_id        = data.aws_ssm_parameter.workers_ami_id.value
  workers_number_min    = var.workers_number_min
  workers_number_max    = var.workers_number_max
  workers_storage_size  = var.workers_storage_size
  commom_tags           = local.commom_tags
  aws_region            = var.aws_region
}

locals {
  commom_tags = {
    ManagedBy   = "terraform"
    ClusterName = "${var.clusters_name_prefix}-${terraform.workspace}"
  }
}
```

this is the output file that generates the VPC parameters to create the cluster

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = module.vpc.eks_cluster_vpc_id
}

output "private_subnet_ids" {
  value = module.vpc.eks_private_subnet_ids
}

output "public_subnets_ids" {
  value = module.vpc.eks_public_subnet_ids
}
```

Comment: "I thought about using Data Sources , but it didn't work it still asks to pass the values during the plan" can you share what you tried here and the output when you run it please? This should work fine but it's not easy to tell where you went wrong as it is currently.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Hi , thanks for your answer , I tried using the terraform state approach , but as I said it is not a good practice , what I need to know is how to get the output values ​​from the testcluster-vpc folder and use it in the main.tf file inside the testcluster folder, so you don't need to pass these values ​​to Tfvars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i undesrtand , you want to use output variables from one terraform folder to another . One way to achieve this using `terraform_remote_state`

EX : In `testcluster-vpc` folder, expose outputs in map

```
output "testclusters_vpc_net" {
  value = {
    "vpc_id"             = module.vpc.eks_cluster_vpc_id
    "private_subnet_ids" = module.vpc.eks_private_subnet_ids
    "public_subnets_ids" = module.vpc.eks_public_subnet_ids
    
  }
}
```

In `testcluster` folder refer to your terraform state file of `testcluster-vpc` folder like

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "testcluster-vpc" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    bucket = "<bucket-name>"
    key    = "<path-to-tfstate-file>"
    region = "<region>"
  }
}
```

Now you can access the values as

```
vpc_id = data.terraform_remote_state.testcluster-vpc.outputs.testclusters_vpc_net.vpc_id
```

Note: to achieve this `testclusters_vpc_net` should always run before `testcluster` folder to access the updated remote state and its outputs

Comment: Please stop recommending using the remote state data source for things that have a native data source. It's overly complicated and a pain to configure in comparison. It also doesn't solve this specific issue because the OP tried using the proper native data sources but had a variable prompt still so it looks like they misconfigured things.

Comment: can you explain why its overly complicated and pain to use remote state ? Its simple configuration , and  its an alternative to use native date sources and solves the purpose. I dont see how it doesnt solve .

Comment: @SuryaPrakashPatel
looking in the official documentation , it seems that this way using state is supported by Hashicorp , I saw this excerpt in the documentation `+ subnets = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.public_subnet_ids`  but now this error appears


`Error: Unsupported attribute

on main.tf line 4, in module "testcluster":
4: public_subnets = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.public_subnet_ids

data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs is object with 3 attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "public_subnet_ids".
`

Comment: make sure you have applied plan and apply and make sure outputs and their format are present in state file  where you are reffering to . you can check by dumping state file or use terraform output command to check

Comment: @SuryaPrakashPatel hello , i did the tests here and now it worked , thank you very much !  , what was wrong in the previous run was that the `private_subnet_ids` was missing a ( . )

Comment: @MiltonJesus Appreciate it if you accept or upvote the answer, only if you think this helped to solve the issue.